# Unsupported projection mongodb in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

my code is :

```js
result = await mongoDBO.collection(collectionName).find({id: data.id},{projection : {'_id' : 0}}).toArray();
```

But I get the following error

```
Unsupported projection option: projection: { _id: 0 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `projection` property. Just send the projection object:

```js
result = await mongoDBO.collection(collectionName).find({ id: data.id }, { '_id': 0 }).toArray();
```

Comment: thanks for your help . I applied the changes and it worked

Comment: You are welcome. Consider also accepting and upvoting my answer, so other people that have the same issue would know it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I also tested this way and it worked

```
await mongoDBO.collection(collectionName).find({id:data.id}).project({'_id' : 0}).toArray()
```